# iOS clear the cache after my phonegap app exits. How to persist user generated data to use offline usage

Tags: ios, caching, cordova, local-storage, offline

The application developed in phonegap has user generated data like images and audio. 
I apply following code to store:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

The application has rejected from iTunes store because user generated data can not be saved in icoloud and should be "iOS Data Storage Guidelines".

I have changed the parameters to following to store application data genereted during usage on phone:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

The application approved on itunes store but every time exist app all caches files removing can not be used in offline.

How can i solve the problem? Keep the data not to download again and again?

Comment: Did you perhaps figure this one out? I have the same problem; downloading and using images on Android works, but can't download even to "file:///var/mobile/Applications/<GUID>/Documents/" with FileTransfer huhh. If I use temporary it's of no use for me ...